# Drag and Drop objects from one CCLayer to another

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have three layers in my `CCScene`. `MainLayer` which contains `GameLayer` and `HUDLayer`. This is what it looks like now:

```
[ z-Order        ] | [ Layer ]
==============================
  3 ( Top Most )   | HUDLayer
  2 ( Middle )     | GameLayer
  1 ( Bottom )     | MainLayer
```

I have added touch listeners (`ccTouchBegan`, `ccTouchMoved`, and `ccTouchEnded`) on my `MainLayer` which calls `GameLayer`'s method `getTouchedObject( CCPoint p_Loc )` which returns the touched object in that layer.

I am now able to successfully 'touch' a specific object in the `MainLayer`. Now, what I want to do is to drag the object touched and put it into the `HUDLayer`. When I was working with just one layer, I was able to drag and drop different objects with no problem but the need to implement `CCLayer`s came so I divided the main layer into three different layers.

Answers doesn't need to be cocos2d-x. I understand a bit of Obj-C and can translate Obj-C into C++ so cocos2d answers are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: assume that your object OBJ is a CCObject*, when you get this instance, you can hold it by calling OBJ->retain(), and later you can use OBJ->removeFromParentAndCleanup(false),and you can add this object to whatever layer you want, for example HUDLayer->addChild(OBJ); and finally, remember to call OBJ->release() to keep the right reference number.

Comment: The object I am dragging is a `CCSprite` which is a child of a `CCNode ` which is a child of another `CCNode` which is a child of GameLayer. Can I implement that on `CCNode` instances?

Comment: sure you can without any problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do it, is probably:

1. Add a new `CCLayer` on the very top called `HoverLayer` or something. This is for modularity.
2. As soon as a sprite is touched on any layer, remove it from that layer, and add it as a child of `HoverLayer` at the same position. The user will not "see" anything changed.
3. On touch up, after dragging the sprite, detect if the sprite is within the `HUDLayer` or not.
4. Remove the sprite from the `HoverLayer` and add it to the appropriate layer.

NOTES:

- You can use the `HUDLayer` instead of the `HoverLayer`, but your class will be messy.
- Of course, if you keep the touched sprite at the `GameLayer` while dragging, it will end up behind the `HUDLayer` at some point, so moving the sprite to a top layer is a must.
- The code to implement the given solution is trivial. Nothing special to do, really.

Comment: I think he should combine your answer with my code to make an implementation :P

Comment: I have the draggable object a child of a CCNode which is a child of GameLayer, something like this: `MainLayer` -> `GameLayer` -> `Object` -> `Draggable Object` So I can just remove the `Draggable Object` from `Object` and add it on the `HUDLayer`?

Comment: what type does your getTouchedObject() return?

Comment: @LanceGray, I don't see a problem with that.. You can either remove the `Object`, and add it to `HoverLayer`, or remove the `DraggableObject` only, but do it appropriately, or even create a new sprite and set the one you have as `Hidden`! I left the details of the implementation for you to decide.

Comment: Might be simpler if I give it names: `(CCLayer) MainLayer` -> `(CCLayer) GameLayer` -> `(CCNode) MyClassA` -> `(CCNode) MyClassB` -> `(CCSprite) MyClassBSprite`. `getTouchedObject()` returns `(CCNode) MyClassB` and I just have a public `get` method to move the `(CCSprite) MyClassBSprite` around.

Comment: @m.ding Neat piece of code you have there. I don't speak cocos2d-x unfortunately :)

Comment: The draggable object contains other data such as `speed`, `life`, etc. If I remove it from parent (`removeFromParentAndCleanup( true )`) would I lose all those other data?

Comment: @LanceGray As long as you retain the object, nothing will be lost. All the data is preserved.

Comment: I just checked the source code, you won't lost data, but you will lost the running actions and all schedules

Comment: @m.ding by false, you are just telling the sprite not to clean up the actions (ie if the sprite has a running action, the action will not stop). Variables are not affected whether it was false or true AFAIK.

Comment: @Mazyod yeah I just notice that and I edited my answer, oops :) thanks, Maz

Comment: @m.ding np, that was a nice little chat xD

Comment: I tried it and it worked like a charm. I have `MyClassB` objects contained in an `std::vector` in `MyClassA` and I was thinking `MyClassB` would be removed from the `std::vector` if I use `removeFromParentAndCleanup( true )`. I thought `removeFromParentAndCleanup( true )` calls the destructor of that object.

Answer (score 3):

I will provide an implementation here:

```
CCSprite* tmpSprite = getTouchedObject();
tmpSprite->retain();
tmpSprite->removeFromParentAndCleanup(false);
//do something here to get a pointer to you HUDLayer
//for example myHud = GameLayer->getChildByTag(HUD_TAG);
myHud->addChild(tmpSprite);
tmpSprite->release();
```